# C++ algorithm find_if in map

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, std

I want to find pair in map and just print it.
This is my code:

```
    std::map<std::string, std::string> mLoginPasswordMap{ "test", "test2" };
    std::string key1("test");
    std::string value1("test2");
    auto it = std::find_if( mLoginPasswordMap.cbegin(),
                        mLoginPasswordMap.cend(),
                        [&key1, &value1]( const auto& elem )
                        {
                            return ( key1 == elem.first && value1 == elem.second );
                        });

    if( it != mLoginPasswordMap.cend() )
    {
        std::cout << it->first << endl;
        std::cout << it->second << endl;
    }
    if( it == mLoginPasswordMap.cend() )
    {
        std::cout << "No pair in map" << endl;
    }
```

and I receive this kind of error when program is compiling:

```
usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:273:4:   required from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::map(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = const char*; _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
main.cpp:23:79:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:146:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::pair(const char&)’
  146 |  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
      |    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: That has nothing to do with searching, you are initializing the map incorrectly. You have to provide pairs, not individual elements. `mLoginPasswordMap{ {"key", "value" } };` for example.

Comment: Please don't paste error messages as images or external links, just copy/paste them as text directly into the question.

Comment: Off-topic: Any code like `if(condition) { } if(!condition) { }` is better written as `if(condition) { } else { }`...

Comment: Also note that `std::map` is internally sorted, so doing linear search `std::find_if()` is possible but is not that efficient. Take a look at [`std::map::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find).

Comment: *"This is my code:"* -- this does not look like a complete example. You should wrap this in a function so that people can copy your code block, give it to a compiler, and reproduce your result (c.f. [mre]). This could be as simple as adding the line `void foo() {` before what you have and the line `}` after. Well, also listing the needed `#include` directives in the code block would be a considerate touch.

Comment: *"`main.cpp:23:79:`"* -- which line is 23? It 's impossible for us to count because your code is incomplete. Which character is 79? It really helps the people volunteering to help you if you save them the trouble of counting characters. **Also:** if line 23 is not `std::cout << "No pair in map" << endl;`, why does your **example** extend past the line with the syntax error? Once your example code is long enough to demonstrate the error, all that should be need are closing braces (possibly other syntax-closing elements, but no others come to mind right away).

Answer (score 0):

Just fill the map in the simple way, instead:

```
    std::map<std::string, std::string> mLoginPasswordMap;
    mLoginPasswordMap["test"] = "test2";
```

then your code will work.

That said, this is not the way to use a `map`. If you absolutely need a search (doesn't really apply to a map), a better way is:

```
    std::map<std::string, std::string> mLoginPasswordMap;
    mLoginPasswordMap["test"] = "test2";

    std::string key1("test");
    std::string value1("test2");

    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it;
    for(it = mLoginPasswordMap.lower_bound(key1); it != mLoginPasswordMap.upper_bound(key1); it++)
    {
        if (it->second == value1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if( it != mLoginPasswordMap.cend() && it->second == value1)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << endl;
        std::cout << it->second << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No pair in map" << endl;
    }
```

This way, you actually leverage the `map` and don't traverse it all. And `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` are the normal way to search a range.

Now, if you have a `map` and want to search for a given key:

```
    std::map<std::string, std::string> mLoginPasswordMap;
    mLoginPasswordMap["test"] = "test2";

    std::string key1("test");
    std::string value1("test2");

    auto it = mLoginPasswordMap.find(key);
    if(it != mLoginPasswordMap.end())
    {
        std::cout << it->first << endl;
        std::cout << it->second << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No pair in map" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` still seems a lot more complicated than just `mLoginPasswordMap.find(key1);`

Comment: ugh. yes, that is correct :-). Let's say this answer is forward-looking to a multimap, and a more complex predicate